# Creating a custom column with different group names for same row element in redshift

Tags: sql, grouping, amazon-redshift, rollup

I have table that looks like this in redshift

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | element1 | 100 |
| 2 | element2 | 200 |
| 3 | element3 | 100 |
| 4 | element4 | 50 |
| 1 | element1 | 100 |
| 2 | element2 | 200 |
| 5 | element5 | 250 |

I am looking to create a custom column on the fly called groups like group1 will contain id (1,2,4) and group2 will be (1,2,5) and the expected output is like.  Expected output will be

| cus col | value |
| --- | --- |
| group1 | 650 |
| group2 | 850 |
| 3 | 100 |

[table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qU9Y.png)

I tried the below query with case statement but group2 does not add elements 1 and 2 and only gets added in group1

> select case when id in (1,2,4) then 'group1
> when id in (1,2,5) then 'group2'
> else id end,
> sum(value) from sample
> group by 1

Answer (score 0):

```
--drop table element_data;
create table element_data(id number(10),name varchar2(10),value number(10));

insert into element_data values(1,'e1',100);
insert into element_data values(2,'e2',200);
insert into element_data values(3,'e3',100);
insert into element_data values(4,'e4',50);
insert into element_data values(1,'e1',100);
insert into element_data values(2,'e2',200);
insert into element_data values(5,'e5',250);
select * from element_data;


select sum(output) from(
select  unique ID,(case when id=1 or id =5 or id=2 then
              sum(value) over(partition by name ) end) output from element_data)
              UNION all
              select sum(output) from(
select  unique ID,(case when id=1 or id =2 or id=4 then
              sum(value) over(partition by name ) end) output from element_data)
              union all
              select sum(output) from(
select  unique ID,(case when id=3 then
              sum(value) over(partition by name ) end) output from element_data)
              ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
case 
when id in (1,2,4) then 'group1' 
when id in (1,2,5) then 'group2' 
else 'other' end as mygroup,
value
FROM yourTable
)
SELECT mygroup,
sum(value) over (partition by position mygroup order by mygroup) as totalValue
FROM cte
group by mygroup
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky because the groups are overlapping.  I would suggest:

```
with group_mapping as (
      select 1 as id, 'group1' as grp union all
      select 2 as id, 'group1' as grp union all
      select 4 as id, 'group1' as grp union all
      select 1 as id, 'group2' as grp union all
      select 2 as id, 'group2' as grp union all
      select 5 as id, 'group3' as grp
     )
select coalesce(gm.grp, t.id::text) as grp, sum(value)
from t left join
     group_mapping gm
     on gm.id = t.id
group by coalesce(gm.grp, t.id::text);
```

Note:  If you have a table with the group mapping information, then a CTE is not needed for that purpose.

If the groups were not overlapping then an alternative would be aggregating by a `case` expression.